# react JS implement image Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

in my react app I'm using a package `react-dropzone`. and it works quite nice. but I can't figure out to prevent duplicate images.

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
 const [found, setFound] = useState(false);
 const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: {
      "image/*": [],
    },

    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      acceptedFiles.filter(
        (el, idx) =>
          idx ===
          files.findIndex((elm) => elm.name === el.name && setFound(true))
      );
      if (!found) {
        setFiles((prev) => [
          ...prev,
          ...acceptedFiles.map((file) =>
            Object.assign(file, {
              preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
            })
          ),
        ]);
      }
    },
  });
```

how can I prevent image duplication? and also make limitations on it? only 4 - 9 images can be uploaded?